# How to open multiple pages in the same app?

Tags: aurelia

I know that Aurelia is a framework for an SPA but I need to open multiple pages at the same time inside the browser.

I want to host each page (view/viewmodel) within a draggable div and have more than one open at the same time. They will be selected by the User from a menu.

I have looked at viewPorts but cannot see how they will help in this problem.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at the following articles for some ideas: 
https://www.sitepoint.com/composition-aurelia-report-builder/
http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-drag-and-drop/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do this.

You say pages, but basically they are components. Every component has a HTML (view) and JS (view-model) file. They can be included as custom-elements.

So if you want multiple possible components on one page, all you need to do is create one component that has a placeholder for those views.

Probably, you would want something looking like this:

[running Gist example](https://gist.run/?id=b66266719e47b4d04539e10326948cce)

```
<template>
  <require from="./page1"></require>
  <require from="./page2"></require>

  <page1></page1>

  <hr>

  <page2></page2>
</template>
```

You can create loop for all elements you want to display, if you need multiple instances of the same page, and put a `repeat.for` on the elements:

HTML:

```
<template>
  <require from="./page1"></require>
  <require from="./page2"></require>

  <page1 repeat.for="i of page1instances"></page1>

  <hr>

  <page2 repeat.for="i of page2instances"></page2>
</template>
```

JS:

```
export class App {
  const page1Instances = 4;
}
```

Making them drag&droppable works like every other element, there are many solutions for that to be found. Just make the `<page1>` and `<page2>` draggable.